# $_SESSION setting waits till end of script

Tags: php, global-variables, session-variables

**What I want:** The $_SESSION variable should equal "Stage 1" for the first 5 seconds of the script, and then should change to "Stage 2".

**What I get:** The $_SESSION variable is not set at all until the 5 seconds are over, at which point it gets set to "Stage 1" and immediately "Stage 2".

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['variable']='Stage 1';

sleep(5);

$_SESSION['variable']='Stage 2';
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I need this code concept for being able to get the $_SESSION variable on another page using AJAX for the purpose of real-time tracking of the progress of a long PHP script.)

---

**EDIT:** I think I realize the problem: While the server is busy with the `sleep` called in one page, the server is "hung" until that script finishes. So when trying to retrieve the `$_SESSION['variable']` on another page, the page just waits *(Connecting...)* until the first page completed its `sleep`, and only then does the server send the second page to the browser.

**Do I just need to upgrade to a better server?** (I'm currently using 1and1's cheapest hosting plan)

Comment: Do you have to use PHP? Or can you use Javascript too?

Comment: I tested this and my script waits 5 seconds. `echo` out the values of the `$_SESSION['variable']` and `date('h:i:s')` to see what the time stamps are for stage 1 and stage 2.

Comment: @WasteD **Re: Javascript:** on the page that sets the $_SESSION variables I cannot use javascript, it must stay server side. The page that I want to retrieve the variables uses jQuery's AJAX fetch a PHP file which echoes the `$_SESSION['variable']`.

Comment: @Daniel_ZA Good idea about echoing the time stamps. The result was indeed 5 seconds apart! This makes the question stronger, why I cannot retrieve the "Stage 1" $_SESSION['variable'] until "Stage 2" happens already? Can it be it's because the server is busy with the sleeping script?

Comment: From the code in your question, the $_SESSION['variable'] will have the value of stage 2 because it gets assigned this new value after 5 seconds, so by the end of the script it's value is stage 2. You could perform 2 ajax calls 5 seconds apart - one for each stage.

Comment: @Daniel_ZA I **am** indeed calling my AJAX twice. In fact, I'm calling it once every second with `setInterval`, yet still I can only retrieve the page after stage 2 happens. As I noted, I think the server is not responding to my AJAX requests until it finished the `sleep`. Maybe the PHP on my server can't do more than one process at a time, so the AJAX request has to wait until the PHP `sleep` script is done.

Answer (score 0):

I saw something in another post maybe this works for you to.

> Try adding `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of the document. Chances are
>   it is reaching the "maximum execution time" and causing the script to
>   terminate.